# One app for mobile devices and TV's in Huawei AppGallery

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, harmonyos, appgallery, appgallery-connect

My app is released in Huawei AppGallery for mobile devices and tablets.
But my app has both interfaces for mobile and TV.

I see that it's not possible to release one app for all device types like it is working on Google Play Store.

I tried to create one more app with the same data (which was very annoying to copy all the information from one app to another like description, screenshots for every language) and selected "TV" in AppGallery Connect, but I can't upload the same App bundle, it says that my package name already exists.

How can I create the same app but for TV with the same App Signing, with the same package name, because I have In-App purchases in my app and they must work on mobile devices and TV's (Vision)? I don't want to build 2 different apps.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For details about how to release an application to Huawei AppGallery, you could refer  [the following website](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/distribution/app/agc-help-harmonyos-releaseapp-0000001126380068) might help you.

Comment: Hello, it doesn't answer my question. I don't need HarmonyOS app, i want to release an Android app. I already released Android app in Huawei AppGallery but for mobile devices only. I want to release the same app for TV's (Vision TV) and users must see their In-App purchases on mobile and TV. How can i do that?

Comment: Currently, the Android app does not support to release in both mobile phone and TV, but the HarmonyOS app does, so you may consider releasing the HarmonyOS app.